What setting controls the range of client IP addresses in an OpenVPN server?
I have an OpenVPN 2.5.9 server on Ubuntu 22.04. It was configured by someone else, and works properly for 4 Linux clients. A connection between the clients is an important part of the use case.
I would like to add a Windows client. I used the certificate and key from one of the Linux systems (which is offline) in the Windows client.
The Windows client connects, but cannot ping the VPN server or any of the other clients.
In the server configuration, these are the only un-commented lines:
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert my_server.crt
key my_server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1

I used the existing client files client4.crt and client4.key for the windows client.
The files client4.crt, client4.key, and ca.crt are in the C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config folder, along with client4.ovpn, below:
client
dev               tun1
proto             udp
remote            10.75.31.11 1194
script-security   2
resolv-retry      infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb              3
ca                ca.crt
cert              "client4.crt"
key               "client4.key"
comp-lzo
cipher            AES-256-CBC

The configuration appears to be defaulting to the "net30" mode, where each client is put on an /30 subnet, using the middle two of the four addresses. The server end of the tunnel is 1 lower than the client address.
The 4 Linux clients were assigned IP addresses of:
10.8.0.22,     10.8.0.10,     10.8.0.6,     10.8.0.26

The server is at 10.8.0.1
The new windows client is assigned 10.8.0.34.
It cannot ping the server end of it's link 10.8.0.33, the server at 10.8.0.1, or another client at 10.8.0.6
The server config points to a log file at /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log. It contains:
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,2024-11-16 23:42:17
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
client4,10.75.31.12:59106,13991,3394,2024-11-16 23:42:11
client2,10.250.32.11:50632,46677,47326,2024-11-16 21:02:55
client3,10.250.32.8:39521,45671,47286,2024-11-16 21:02:55
client1,10.250.32.22:53990,104410,104646,2024-11-16 21:02:55
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
10.8.0.22,client2,10.250.32.11:50632,2024-11-16 21:02:56
10.8.0.34,client4,10.75.31.12:59106,2024-11-16 23:42:11
10.8.0.6,client1,10.250.32.22:53990,2024-11-16 23:42:03
10.8.0.26,client3,10.250.32.8:39521,2024-11-16 21:02:56
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,4
END

Everything looks reasonable there as client4 is originating from 10.75.31.12.
From the windows client log I see this:
Sat Nov 16 23:50:32 2024 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1731819032,ASSIGN_IP,,10.8.0.34,
Sat Nov 16 23:50:32 2024 open_tun, tt->ipv6=0
Sat Nov 16 23:50:32 2024 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet] opened: \\.\Global\{7D8E400D-77CB-493A-AA2B-6E4A743EC55B}.tap
Sat Nov 16 23:50:32 2024 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Sat Nov 16 23:50:32 2024 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.34/255.255.255.252 on interface {7D8E400D-77CB-493A-AA2B-6E4A743EC55B} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.33, lease-time: 31536000]
Sat Nov 16 23:50:32 2024 NOTE: FlushIpNetTable failed on interface [25] {7D8E400D-77CB-493A-AA2B-6E4A743EC55B} (status=5) : Access is denied.  
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1731819037,ADD_ROUTES,,,
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.33
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Access is denied.   [status=5 if_index=25]
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 Route addition fallback to route.exe
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 Initialization Sequence Completed
Sat Nov 16 23:50:37 2024 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1731819037,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.8.0.34,10.75.31.11

The failure of the route add command is a likely issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it. OpenVPN runs as a service, so I'm not sure how it could be further elevated in privilege.
I was able to run the route command from the log in an elevated CMD window, and it succeeded.
C:\Windows\system32>C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.33
 OK!

After that runs, there is still no connectivity from the windows client to the VPN. Windows Firewall is off while debugging this issue.
The file  /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt is supposed to track client IP addresses.
client1,10.8.0.4,
client,10.8.0.8,
client1,10.8.0.12,
client,10.8.0.16,
my_server,10.8.0.20,
client3,10.8.0.24,
client4,10.8.0.32,

I'm not sure why client1 is listed twice. Maybe an artifcact of early testing, along with the client without a number?
Should I delete ipp.txt and let the server re-create it?
Is there any other setting or file that would limit the total number of clients?
There is a server setting for
;max-clients 100
but it is commented out. The clients are connecting, just not passing traffic from the windows client. The non-working windows client has the highest address at 10.8.0.32. Is there some other setting that controls the allowed range of addresses supported in a configuration using the client-to-client option?

I believe ultimately you want to fix the connectivity for the Windows client, not to just know how to control the automatic allocation range? Then you'd better ask that. Currently the question is worded like you don't care about connectivity, just mention it as a curious fact; I can answer that, but I suspect it won't be what you really want. // That said, the problem is not likely with the IP. Most likely it's firewall on Windows side. You can temporary set verb 6 in the config and confirm that OpenVPN exchanges packets (which will be logged); if it does, problem is not with OpenVPN.

The failure of the route add command is a likely issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it. It is. Give OpenVPN more privileges. It absolutely needs to be able to add routes. Run it as a system or as an admin. I remember seeing this problem first with Windows 7 (i.e. it wasn't with XP); but you don't say which version you have. I'm not a Windows admin, unfortunately, I don't know how to "elevate it more", but nevertheless, this inability to add routes is at least the part of the cause.
